# Load customer group code by default

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer, resource-model

I'm working on functionality that cares about the customer group. Currently we are loading the group code whenever we need it:

`Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getcustomerGroupId())->getCustomerGroupCode();`

What I'd like to do is just go ahead and have the customer model get this bit of data when the customer is being loaded. How can I accomplish this? Further, is it the most practical way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly simple. Create an observer on the `customer_load_after` event. As the method to run, use the following snippet of code (untested) to load the group code from the DB, and then to set it on the newly-loaded customer object.

```
public function customerLoadAfter($observer) 
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    $resource = $customer->getResource();
    $select = $resource->getReadConnection()
        ->select()
        ->from($resource->getTable('customer/group'), ['customer_group_code'])
        ->where('entity_id = ?', $customer->getGroupId();

    $customer->setGroupCode($resource->fetchOne($select);
}
```

You can then retreive it with `$customer->getGroupCode();`.

This is probably the most practical way to do this. You could rewrite the customer resource model to `join` the data in when loading the model, and while it would be a tad bit more performant, it would definitely take a lot longer/be more complicated to write, and wouldn't be as clean as the event-based approach.

Comment: I was hoping it would be simply adding to the list of entities the customer model loads, but it makes sense that I'd have to rewrite the resource model and do a join. This is very clean, thanks!